# What can I do if I need to reach a function in child class and I have its parent reference?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, parent-child

Sorry for the title, I could not imagine a more specific title but let me explain.

Let's say we have 2 different characters. One is Ally which is our character and the other one is Enemy. And let's say we are immortal so Ally cannot die.

```
public class Ally : BaseCharacter
    {
        public override void Attack() { }
    }

    public class Enemy : BaseCharacter
    {
        public void Die() { }
        public override void Attack() { }
    }

    public class BaseCharacter
    {
        public BaseCharacterData baseCharacterData;

        public virtual void Attack() { }
    }
```

Here, Attack() function is common between these child classes. But Die() function is not.

And we have data classes for these classes.

```
    public class AllyData : BaseCharacterData
    {
    }

    public class EnemyData : BaseCharacterData
    {
        public string health;
    }

    public class BaseCharacterData
    {
        public string name;
    }
```

And also here, NAME variable is common and HEALTH is not (cuz Ally cannot die).

The problem is this, when I try to create BaseCharacter from another script I assign CharacterData to Ally and it's just fine.

But when I create Enemy, Enemy's health will not be set (I can set it from somewhere else somehow maybe but it's a problem when I need to reach it as well).
Also, let's say we have another class called TEMP and one of its functions takes CharacterData. But it will not be able to reach HEALTH if that CharacterData belongs to an Enemy or it will not be able to call Die() function from BaseCharacter script of Enemy cuz its not common.

This whole scenario is not a real one and does not make sense but I try to simplify it and tell what my problem looks like.

My question is, Is there something I'm doing wrong or this scenario just need a better structure to achieve my goals?

I'm open to all suggestions or solutions but I'm not trying to solve my problem easily or solve it in bad ways. Just trying to find the right ways.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Comparing like `if (CharacterData is EnemyData)` and then casting is not an option here cuz I already know how to do this but it's not a preferred solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Death is not something that is called upon the character. It is something that happens in response to something happening to the character. Things that can happen to a character:

- drank a poison of potency P,
- got hit with a rock of weight W, to body part B,
- got hit with an arrow of weight W, speed V, with enchantment E, to body part B
- fell down to an object O (poisoned spikes or plain old ground)
- got hit with a magic spell named "just die already"

So these are your methods. Enemy can die from them, and ally can't, but even an ally can experience some other effects (dizziness, unconsciousness, etc.).

Comment: I am telling you to remove method "GetHealth", and add method "DoSomething" that will handle the health manipulation. Only `Enemy` class should know that there is such thing as "health". Everyone else should not know about it.

Comment: Main question now is, are you allowed to remove `GetHealth` method from `Enemy` class? If yes then remove it.

Comment: But technically isn't it a bad thing to create a function that Ally won't use? (Maybe it will use but just assume that it won't use it.)

Comment: I can remove it but Enemy is able to do something that Ally cannot do. This is the actual problem.

Comment: I have already explained it. I don't know how else to explain it. Remove `GetHealth`. No one should know that there is such thing as health. It is internal knowledge of class `Enemy`. Add some other method (or several methods), like `ApplyHit(Object o, Speed s)`. `Ally` override can be empty function. `Enemy` override will decrease its private property `health`.

Comment: Ok I get it. Thanks for your effort and patience.

Comment: You can even introduce new class `InteractionResolver` that would have many methods. One of the methods would be `ResolveHit(Ally a, Object o, Speed s)` and another would be `ResolveHit(Enemy e, Object o, Speed s)`. This class would then know what happens in each case.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a data class that is similar to the baseCharacter class into two types. Why not set the information within the class itself? Eliminate **Alternatives** and **Dublications** The first and most important programming lesson.

```cs
public class Ally : BaseCharacter
{
    public override void Attack() { }
}

public class Enemy : BaseCharacter
{
    public float health;
    public void Die() { }
    public override void Attack() { }
}

public class BaseCharacter
{
    public string name;
    public virtual void Attack() { }
}
```

---

### Access Class

```cs
public void Start()
{
    BaseCharacter character = new Enemy();

    if (character is Enemy myEnemy)
    {
        myEnemy.health = 52; // for e.g
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with you. But at some point creating a class for character's data made sense to me because there can be lots of variables from name to shoes size. And also there can be functions to manipulate data itself within data class or just a ToString() function. Does not make sense?

Comment: @Roduraz You have defined the base character class for this very purpose to cover many variables as well as the same methods. If not, your baseCharacter class will have no field, and this time the baseCharacter itself will be useless.

Comment: Ally and Enemy classes are actually a monoBehaviour. And they have fields like animator, rigid body and other needed controller classes. So to separate them from the data I've created data classes for them (They can be SO like everyone suggests). But I got what you're trying to tell me and it also make sense.

But I want to ask you another question. The question is, even if I put all data fields in monoBehaviour, Health field or Die() function will not be able to be reached from a BaseCharacter reference. So the problem still occurs.

Comment: @Roduraz In the above edition, I wrote the type of access to the class. See if it solves your problem?